# Get Image Path to src when partial view loads ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have this image tag:  `<img src="url goes here" />`

My controller action looks like this:

```
public string GetProfilePhotoPath(){
    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    var userImage = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userId).ProfilePhotoPath;
    return userImage;
}
```

`userImage` contains something like this: `~/Content/img/users/userABCD.png`

Now my question is, how do I call the controller and get the path so I can pass it to `src`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/users/" + ControllerB().GetProfilePhotoPath()" alt="" />
```

example calling from another controller, "ControllerB" will be the actual name of your controller
**ControllerB (receiving part):**

```
var result = new ControllerB().GetProfilePhotoPath();
```

or you can try using a **ViewBag** ?

```
ViewBag.MyString = myString;
```

Then you would use it like

```
img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/img/users/" + @ViewBag.MyString" alt="" />
```